# How to remove write protection from a flash drive?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have received an RO (write-protected) flash drive, and I'm wondering if the write protection can be removed, changing it to R/W.

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? What did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether it's hardware or software protection, this *might* work.

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Type `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/XdY` Where `X` and `Y` are the letters identifying your flash drive

Comment: not work for me. results `/dev/sdb1:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)`

Comment: Also, not work for me. results   `/dev/sdb:     setting readonly to 0 (off)     readonly      =  1 (on)`