# Unable to format a write protected USB Stick

Tags: usb, permissions

Surely there are many many questions on this topic, But I've a reason to believe that this is different.

**Things that I've already tried**

1. Formatting from Nautilus
2. Formatting from Gnome-Disks
3. Creating a new partition table from Gparted
4. Formatting from Gparted
5. `chown` to get ownership
6. remounting with `rw`
7. forcefully remounting wit `ntfs-3g`

---

outputs (mounting)

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdc1 read-write, is write-protected
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379'
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdc1 read-write, is write-protected
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=$(id -u) /dev/sdc1 /media/sumeet/4CCF-3379
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Chown

```
$ sudo chown -R sumeet:sumeet /media/sumeet/4CCF-3379
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/LOST.DIR/134797': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/LOST.DIR': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/.android_secure': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/.cache/tb': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/.cache': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/.log': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/app': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/music': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/video': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/photo': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/misc': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/backup': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/doodle/.nomedia': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/doodle': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya/folder': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379/zapya': Read-only file system
chown: changing ownership of '/media/sumeet/4CCF-3379': Read-only file system
```

dd

```
$ sudo dd if="/dev/zero" of="/dev/sdc1" bs=1M count=10 
dd: error writing '/dev/sdc1': Operation not permitted
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000825744 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

hdparm

```
$ sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

Creating new partition

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system
```

Still isn't working

---

Device info

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
```

Comment: @AndroidDev This wasn't done after making it bootable, I've also tried using mkusb

Comment: Have you tried crating a new partition table?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh - Ah. Well maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745907/how-to-remove-write-protection-from-a-flash-drive/745924#745924) then?

Comment: @Ravexina yes, with gparted

Comment: Was it successful ? (Were you able to write it to the disk?), if it wasn't then use `sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` and press "o" to create a new partition table then "w" to write it to the disk.

Comment: @Ravexina let me try that

Comment: @Ravexina tried it, updated the results

Comment: `sudo fdisk /dev/sdc` not `sdc1`

Comment: @Ravexina sorry about that, updated the results

Comment: `sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc` then again try creating a new partition table using fdisk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60779/discussion-between-sumeet-deshmukh-and-ravexina).