# Write protection error in USB?

Tags: usb, read-only

I have 8 GB USB. The USB is made bootable using multisystem software. I use this USB as writable removable disk alongside bootable for a long time. Some days ago, I inserted the USB in a windows pc and then that pc put a application named `USBSecurity.exe` in my USB without my permission.

See the screenshot of my USB.

[image]

Now, I can't write anything in my USB. It is read-only. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT**
There is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745907/how-to-remove-write-protection-from-a-flash-drive) asked earlier. But, my question is bit different that my USB is bootable but that not. And the answer provided to that question doesn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove write protection from a flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745907/how-to-remove-write-protection-from-a-flash-drive)

Comment: @AndroidDev that's solution not work for me and that USB not bootable but mine is.

Comment: Would it be OK for you to: 1. copy the personal files from your USB drive to another drive; 2. create a new partition table and file system (with or without an operating system using Multisystem or some other tool)? Or is it important to repair the current content of the USB drive (more difficult)?

Comment: Where is your USB pen mounted ? I am guessing /media/something ? What are the permissions of your mount point ?

Comment: @sudodus I know that this will work.  But, I don't do this because then I have to make the USB bootable again that is time consuming. I have about 3 OS in the USB.

Comment: @hatterman yes,  you are wright. `/media/alhelal$ ls -al` results `drwx------  18 alhelal alhelal 8192 জানু    1  1970 MULTISYSTEM` MULTISYSTEM is my pendrive.

Comment: The date seems wrong, 1970 ? Anyway, as a test perform chmod 777 on your mount point, before mounting your pen. You can always change permissions to something more sensible later. Also, are you logged in as alhelal ?

Comment: I see that you want to repair the pendrive. I hope that you will save time and effort compared to copying the files and creating the three operating systems again. *Good luck* :-) By the way, systems in USB pendrives are very sensitive. When you have a working drive again, please *make a cloned copy* of it, so that you can easily get back to a working system, when there are problems next time.

Comment: @hatterman `/media/alhelal$ sudo chmod 777 USB/`
`/media/alhelal$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 USB/`
results `mount: block device /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Comment: When the method suggested by Android Dev did not work, I had hoped that @hatterman's method would work. Did you perform the `sudo chmod 777` on your mount point ***before*** mounting? -- If still no luck, maybe the following links might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035

Comment: Why did you chmod 777 /USB ? Your pen drive is mounted to /media/alhelal so you need to chmod 777 /media/alhelal.

Comment: @hatterman I didn't `chmod 777 /USB` but,  `chmod 777 USB/`

Comment: I am still not sure why, I suggested that you chmod your mount point. So ..... chmod 777 /media/alhelal. This will give your mount point (hence your pen once mounted) read/write/execute permissions for everyone. Its a quick test to see if the issue relates to permissions.

Comment: @sudodus Finally, I tried to create new partition table using `gparted` but the options are disable. And, `multisystem` doesn't load the pendrive, instead results error.

Comment: At this stage I suggest that you try find out, if there is a problem with the partition table or file system(s) or some file(s) in the drive (a *software problem*), or if there is a *hardware problem*, that the USB drive itself is damaged. So I suggest that you try according to the list 'The drive is read-only ...' in this link, and try to restore it to a standard storage device (after copying files you want to keep to some other drive), https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035